# istream_iterator, black magic?

Tags: c++, c++11, iostream, istream-iterator

I don't understand why the second argument for_each is an empty iterator. Can someone explain this to me, please?

```
fstream("datfile.txt"); 
for_each(istream_iterator<string>(datfile), istream_iterator<string>(), rand_func);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a special "sentinel" value, whose only purpose is to return the value `true` when compared with another `istream_iterator()` that has reached EOF.

Answer (score 3):

The default constructed `istream_iterator` is used as a sentinel that denotes the end of stream condition. When reading from the `istream` ends, the first iterator input to `for_each` will equal this sentinel iterator, thus terminating the `for_each`.